# Declare function return type and variable with the returing type of function template

Tags: c++

Is using `decltype` for function template with arguments substitution the most straightforward and recommended way to get the type of function template return value?

Let's say, I want to declare my function return type and a variable based on `std::distance` return type. Is it correct and best approach to do so:

```
//Iterators expected
auto func(auto first, auto last) -> decltype(std::distance(first, last)) {
    decltype(std::distance(first, last)) distance = 0;

    while (first != last) {
        // Some actions where distance will be calculated
        distance = std::distance(...,...);
        first = ... ;
    }

    return distance;
}
```

Of course, I can use `ptrdiff_t` as a resulting type, but for me is seems inconsistent.

Comment: The code shown makes me wonder why you bother calculating the distance yourself and instead just use `std::distance`. Maybe casting the result to `int` or something before hand.

Comment: @sweenish, updated the code; is it better shows the intention now? I will calculate the `distance` with std::distance, that's why I need its type. Type 'int' is wrong here, definitely. On some architectures it could be less (its sizeof) than the type I need and it will cause overflow.

Comment: In this example C++20 `std::iter_difference_t<decltype(first)>` might be useful. But I take it the question is really about the more general case.

Comment: @aschepler, thank you, this helps in this particular case and you are right again, the question is about more general case as it is stated in the title, there are many places in code when I need to declare variable being unable to call the function for this, like in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to really answer whats "best", but I would say your approach is correct. Although it can probably be made nicer in some ways.

Firstly, I would drop the trailing return type for the function. Just let it deduce the return type from the implementation, that way you only have to write the unwieldy `decltype` construct once, in the declaration of the `distance` variable.

Secondly, [std::invoke_result_t](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of) might be more readable, however you will run into problems because `std::distance` is a function template. The following should work, but you can argue whether it's better or worse than the `decltype` approach:

```cpp
template<typename Iterator>
auto func(Iterator first, Iterator last) {
    std::invoke_result_t<std::distance<Iterator>, Iterator, Iterator> distance = 0;

    while (first != last) {
        // Some actions where distance will be calculated
        distance = std::distance(...,...);
        first = ... ;
    }

    return distance;
}
```

Lastly, if possible, you can avoid any of the decltype/invoke_result shenanigans if you can adjust your code such that it directly returns the result of `std::distance`. I can't say whether this is possible for your use case, but an example:

```cpp
auto func(auto first, auto last) {
    while (first != last) {
        first = ... ;
        if (...) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return std::distance(first, last);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it helps. On the first, I still in two minds about using `auto` for return types especially in cases when function does one thing and returns another thing (like `std::unique`); in such cases having kind of explicit return type helps to understand from the signature what the function intends to return; with `auto` this comes hard. On the second, of course I mean the case when I need a type for intermediate variable 'distance` which must be declared out of the loop where its type comes since it will be used in the loop and after it.